# Custom annotation without using reflection

Tags: spring, maven, annotations

here my Custom annotaiton

```
@interface IcustomAnnotation{
String getCode();
}

class myClass{
@IcustomAnnotation(getCode="SomeData")
public String setID(String ID){
return ID
}
}
```

in that `setID()`, want to use `getCode`,that `getCode` should have random data that generated by `SecureRandom`

```
 static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
```

How to do?

Comment: no idea whats ur problem

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and after reading improve your question.

Comment: Hi @jaiwo99,I have notification class (bean class), for that i want to generate unique random id for each notification using custom annotation .

Comment: show us your notification class where the notification is sent.

Comment: Hi @Bond-JavaBond, This is my notification class